# передача двумерного массива из codeigniter в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет,
В codeigniter 3.1.0 средством pg_query вызываю  PostgreSQL 9.3 функцию с передачей двумерного массива

```
Array
(
    [1] => 18
    [5] => 20
    [3] => 333333
)
```

где ключи это целое а значение может быть целое или строка

Я передал это все как двумерный массив строк

```
select * from funcname( ARRAY [ ARRAY[ '1','18' ], ARRAY[ '5','20' ], ARRAY[ '3','333333' ] ] )
```

и принимаю как массив в цикле

```
create or replace function funcname( IN p_attributes_list varchar(255)[][]  ) returns int as
...
   FOREACH next_attribute_value IN ARRAY p_attribute_list
   LOOP
```

я получаю 6 значений next_attribute_value из массива, а не 3 пары ключ=>значения как хотелось бы ...
А как правильно и можно ли передать ассоциативный массив и если да, то как и как его обработать на сервере?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел возможность задать цикл с шагом:

```
FOR i IN REVERSE 10..1 BY 2 LOOP
    -- i will take on the values 10,8,6,4,2 within the loop
END LOOP;
```

который можно приспособить у моей задаче - но не уверен лучшее ли это решение
и нет ли возможности передать ассоциативный массив ?